# windows installer in different locations depending on os version

Tags: windows, installer

I've got to create an installer, that installs addon files into an existing programs application folder. Depending on the OS (winxp, win7, 32, 64), it could be in a variety of locations.

e.g. 
c:/program files/application
c:/program files (x86)/application

I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this is?

Since the user could have both 32 and 64 bit versions of the software installed, they may need to choose which version they would like to install the files in.

Ive looked at self extracting zip - which seems the best at the moment - but the user will have to input the path to their software

Ive also looked into nsis and batch files, but it's unclear to me how to detect which operating system (that works for all versions) and also a consistent way to find which programs the user has installed, to provide a dialogue for selecting the path to install the files to.

Would appreciate any tips if someone knows a straight forward way of doing this.

Cheers

Ke

Comment: These are variables.  You don't indicate which installer your using.  Most people would just offer two versions of the installer and assume the user wants it installed to Program Files.

Comment: Ive got to create an installer. I havent decided which one to use yet. I thought about this, if its a 32 bit app the x86 in the folder name will be needed on Win7, but not needed on xp - this is not straight forward to work around - seems many installers are needed

Comment: If you use the variables thats done automatically.  If you create a 32-bit application and link it to Program Files it will automatically install to the correct location on a 32-bit operating system and a 64-bit operating system.  **You need to do more research on how to create an installer the correct way**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths like "c:/program files (x86)/" resp  "c:/program files" are known by the OS. If you make them part of your installer instead of relying on the OS, you guarantee incompatibility with future Windows versions. You also guarantee incompatibility with localized versions of Windows (e.g. "c:/archivos de programa", "c:/programme", "c:/pliki programów").

Every installer software (nsis, wix, and many others) offers a way to ask the OS for the path of "program files". Use that. Have a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089647/install-to-program-files-x86-on-64bit-host

Comment: Don't we all just love downvoters who are too lazy to explain?